# Having the error "Error in copy_msts(y, fitted) : x and y should have the same number of observations"

Tags: r, forecasting, economics

Hi I have current the error:

```
"Error in copy_msts(y, fitted) : 
 x and y should have the same number of observations"
```

after running this line of code `tsla_train_forecast= rwf(tsla_train, h=6)`

Here is my code:

```
library(forecast)

library(quantmod)
getSymbols("TSLA",from="2022-09-01", to="2023-06-16")
chartSeries(TSLA, multi.col = TRUE, theme = "white")
summary(TSLA)
Tesla=TSLA$TSLA.Close
plot(Tesla)

Teslamf=meanf(Tesla,h=6)
plot(Teslamf)
Teslamf
Teslamf$fitted
Teslamf$residuals
acf(Teslamf$residuals)
checkresiduals(Teslamf)

tsla_train=TSLA[1:189]
tsla_test=TSLA[190:196]
tsla_test$TSLA.Close

tsla_train_forecast= rwf(tsla_train, h=6)
tsla_train_forecast
tsla_test-tsla_train_forecast$mean
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, it worked fine when I was using AAPL stock data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `rwf()` is designed for univariate time series, and you are using it with a multivariate time series. Unfortunately, the error message isn't helpful. If you use `rwf(tsla_train[,1], h=6)`, the forecasts are produced without error.

A second issue is that you are using xts objects, but the forecast package is designed to handle `ts` objects. Mostly, it will convert `xts` to `ts` on the fly, but occasionally this could cause an error.